# Are there any alternate terminology for trees?

Tags: tree, terminology

The normal terminology seem to be that the node above a node is called parent and nodes below are called children. Is there any alternate terminology.

My concern is that I'm working with genealogy so using "parent" and "children" might lead to confusion. For example representing ancestry as a (binary) tree means that the proband is at the root and it's children (tree terminology) are the parents (genealogy terminology) of the probands. Confused yet?

Comment: The graph to represent genealogy is not a tree.

Comment: @trincot Sometimes it is. In any case there are tree structures anyway and it would be confusing to use parent/children for naming nodes in trees if they doesn't represent actual parent/children.